Issue with agent in my virtual machine in Azure DevOps
i have a Azure pipeline Agent running as a service in a vritual machine in Azure, until last week this agent worked successfully, and now when i wan to create a release gives me this error

Unable to deploy to the target 'name of the target' as the Deployment Group deployment configuration settigns are not met

When i see my deployment group, the target appears as Online
The virtaul machine is running on windows
I unistall and reinstall the agent many times and nothing change (upgrade and downgrade the version)

You can check if the targets in the Deployment group are partially Online. If yes, you can refer to the steps in my answer to add the tags to target and then release pipeline will filter the Online target to run the release.  On the other hand, you can also share more details about the release definition. It will be helpful to investigate this issue.


Unable to deploy to the target 'name of the target' as the Deployment Group deployment configuration settigns are not met

I can reproduce the same issue when the target agents in the Deployment Group are partially online.

You can check if the target agents are all Online in the Deployment Group. If no, you can refer to the following steps to add the tag to Target agent and use it to filter online target in Release Pipeline.
Here are the steps:
Step1: Navigate to  Deployment Groups -> Target Deployment Group -> Targets -> Add tag to required target(Online).
For example: I add an Active tag to the Online Target

Step2: In Release Pipeline, you can set the Target tag in Deployment Group job -> Required tags.
For example:

In this case, it will use the Online Targets of Deployment Group to run the Release Pipeline and not show the error message.
Result:

